# Longitudinal dataset - difference between two dates

Tags: r, time, longitudinal

I have a longitudinal dataset that I imported in R from Excel that looks like this:

```
STUDYID  VISIT#  VISITDate 
1         1      2012-12-19
1         2      2018-09-19
2         1      2013-04-03
2         2      2014-05-14
2         3      2016-05-12
```

In this dataset, each patient/study ID has a different number of visits to the hospital, and their first visit dates which is likely to differ from individual to individual. I want to create a new time variable which is essentially time in years since first visit, so the dataset will look like this:

```
STUDYID  VISIT#  VISITDate   Time(years)
1         1      2012-12-19    0
1         2      2018-09-19    5
2         1      2013-04-03    0
2         2      2014-05-14    1
2         3      2016-05-12    3
```

The reason for creating a time variable like this is to assess differential regression effects over time (which is a continuous variable). Is there any way to create a new time variable like this in R so I can use it as an independent variable in my regression analyses?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `ave` to calculate the minimum of `VISITDate` by `STUDYID` group, then take the date difference with conversion to integer years:

```r
df <- within(df, {
        minVISITDate <- ave(VISITDate, STUDYID, FUN=min)
        Time <- floor(as.double(difftime(VISITDate, minVISITDate, unit="days") / 365))
        rm(minVISITDate)
    })

df
#  STUDYID VISIT#  VISITDate Time
# 1      1      1 2012-12-19    0 
# 2      1      2 2018-09-19    5 
# 3      2      1 2013-04-03    0
# 4      2      2 2014-05-14    1 
# 5      2      3 2016-05-12    3
```

Comment: Do I need to install some packages in RStudio for this code? Also, since my dataset has gone through some rounds of filtering and is now under "mydata", would the code you proposed look like this: mydata <- within(mydata, {
        minVISITDate <- ave(VISITDate, STUDYID, FUN=min)
        Time <- floor(as.double(difftime(VISITDate, minVISITDate, unit="days") / 365))
        rm(minVISITDate)
    })

mydata

Comment: Yes change all `df` instances to your actual data frame name. And no you do not need additional packages to run this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Loading up packages:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
```

Setting up the data:

```
dat <- tribble(~STUDYID , ~VISIT , ~VISITDate ,
               1       ,  1    ,  "2012-12-19",
               1       ,  2    ,  "2018-09-19",
               2       ,  1    ,  "2013-04-03",
               2       ,  2    ,  "2014-05-14",
               2       ,  3    ,  "2016-05-12") %>% 
  mutate(VISITDate = as.Date(VISITDate))
```

Creating the wanted variable:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(STUDYID) %>% 
  mutate(Time = first(VISITDate) %--% VISITDate,
         Time = as.numeric(Time, "years")) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  STUDYID VISIT VISITDate   Time
    <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
1       1     1 2012-12-19  0   
2       1     2 2018-09-19  5.75
3       2     1 2013-04-03  0   
4       2     2 2014-05-14  1.11
5       2     3 2016-05-12  3.11
```

Comment: These seem to be only for specific dates. I have a whole column of VISITDate so it seems impossible to write the code for each row. Would you have an amendment so as to allow for the entire column of dates? Thanks.

Comment: It already does this. If you are experiencing an error with your data that is not presented in the data you provided, please edit your question with the new data so that I can understand why it's acting differently.